# Adding classes randomly from only 3 variables to more then 20 div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have about 20 divs and have 3 hover effects classes. Want to add this 3 hover effects to all divs randomly.

My js is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
viewclasses = 3;
randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (viewclasses - 1)) + 1;
$('.basediv').each(function(i, val) {
   $(this).addClass('view' + randomNumber); 
});
});
</script>
```

I have 20 divs with class .basediv assigned to them

and css class namely 
.view1
.view2
.view3

with this code I am getting all div elements with same effects. Every div elements are having either .view1 or .view2 or .view3 effects.

Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put the random number inside the loop like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
viewclasses = 3;
$('.basediv').each(function(i, val) {
   randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (viewclasses - 1)) + 1;
   $(this).addClass('view' + randomNumber); 
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to move the `randomNumber` into the `each` function:

```
$('.basediv').each(function(i, val) {
   randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (viewclasses - 1)) + 1;
   $(this).addClass('view' + randomNumber); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('.basediv').each(function(i, val) {
    randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (viewclasses - 1)) + 1;
   $(this).addClass('view' + randomNumber); 
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
viewclasses = 3;
$('.basediv').each(function(i, val) {
    randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (viewclasses - 1)) + 1;
   $(this).addClass('view' + randomNumber); 
});
});
```

```css
.basediv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.view1{
    background:orange;
}
.view2{
    background:green;
}
.view3{
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>

<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>

<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
<div class="basediv"></div>
```